# Load Symfony Form Entity type from Entity

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to figure out the correct way to load a Symfony form Entity type with data from an Entity.

The entities I have are User and School.

A User is anyone who can access the application. But a User could be a School.principal or a School.contact or a School.admin

Now say I'm logged in as admin and I want to add another School. When presenting the new school form I want there to be a drop-down that shows all of the existing contacts for this admin's schools.

School.contact is a User entity, like School. principal and School.admin

I can't figure out how to create the QueryBuilder for the form builder. I need to query for all of the logged in user's schools and pull out School.contact for each one. I'm struggling to find the correct way to do this in Symfony.

In the form builder, I'm looking doing this.

```
->add('contact', EntityType::class, array(
                'label'=>'Contact',
                'class'=>'MySecurityBundle:User',
                'query_builder'=>function(EntityRepository $er) use ($userid) {
                    return $er->getContacts($userid);
                }
            ))
```

In MySecurityBundle:User I have getContacts defined.

```
 public function getContacts($userid) {
        $schools = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('MySchoolBundle:School')->findById($userid);
        $uids = array();
        foreach ($schools as $p) {
            $uids[] = $p->getContact()->getId();
        }
        return $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('c')
            ->from('MySecurityBundle:User', 'c')
            ->where('c.id IN (:ids)')
            ->setParameter('ids', $uids)
        ;
    }
```

It seems like I should be able to do a join rather than pulling all of the schools and fetching the contact ids to pipe into the query. All of the examples of joins seem to be joining with the same table. I'm not seeing much on joining other tables. I could do what I want with DQL, but I'm not sure how to get from DQL to the QueryBuilder that the form build Entity type expects to see.

But maybe I'm just approaching this problem totally wrong. It doesn't feel like I'm doing it right, but my brain is stuck.

Comment: Check here for documentation on the query builder: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine you don't keep a reference on the User as to what type of User he is or he can be multiple. From what I can tell you probably want something in along these lines?

```
    return $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('sc.contact') //you can add 'c.name' etc but you need to select something from the base table which is school
        ->from('MySchoolBundle', 'sc')
        ->join('sc.contact', 'c')
        ->join('sc.admin', 'a')
        ->where('a.id = :id')
        ->setParameter(array('id' => $adminId));
    ;
```

Comment: That seems to make sense. I'll try this out and mark it correct.